# How are columns named when creating a dataframe from different dataframe columns?

Tags: r

Assume, I have a dataframe

```
df1 = data.frame(df1.a=1:3, df1.b=1:3, df1.c=1:3)

  df1.a df1.b df1.c
1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3
```

And create a second one from the first one using different selectors:

```
df2 = data.frame(df2.a=df1$df1.a, df2.b=df1[,"df1.b"], df2.c=df1["df1.c"])
```

Why does the column name of the third column get overridden by the original column name and the others don't?

```
  df2.a df2.b df1.c <-- why is this not df2.c??
1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3
```

Comment: you missed a comma `(,)` in `df2.c=df1["df1.c"]` , it should be `df2.c=df1[,"df1.c"]`

Comment: you're putting a `list` (`df1["df1.c"]`) instead of a `vector` (`df1[, "df1.c"]` or `df1[["df1.c"]]`) inside your second `data.frame`, the `name` come with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `df1["df1.a"]` is a data.frame of one column, whereas `df1[,"df1.a"]` is a vector.

Try

```
> class(df1[,"df1.a"])
[1] "integer"
> class(df1["df1.a"])
[1] "data.frame"
```

According to the documentation:

> For a
>        named or unnamed matrix/list/data frame argument that contains a
>        single column, the column name in the result is the column name in
>        the argument.

Therefore, the argument name in

```
data.frame(…, df2.c=df1["df1.c"])
```

is "ignored" and the call treated as

```
data.frame(…, df1.c=df1$df1.c)
```

Of course, the argument name is technically not ignored.

---

As to *why* that is—the column naming is complex:

> How the names of the data frame are created is complex, and the
>        rest of this paragraph is only the basic story.

For example, try

```
data.frame(df2.x = df1[c("df1.a", "df1.b")])
  df2.x.df1.a df2.x.df1.b
1           1           1
2           2           2
3           3           3
```

(Thanks to Roman for pointing to a better part of the documentation.)

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Still, it seems counter-intuitive to me, that the name I *explicitly* specify, is overridden by the implicit name from the dataframe.

Comment: @GregorSturm a better explanation is in the Values section of the `?data.frame`: "For a named or unnamed matrix/list/data frame argument that contains a single column, the column name in the result is the column name in the argument."